# Parameter passed in save() difficult to understand

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I am learning Django from a most recommended and beneficial book named 'Django By Example'. There is a project called Bookmark. I am now stuck in the forms part which is for downloading the image and saving image object to the database. I could understand validation part(clean_url) and also downloading part. I could not get into the parameter passed in to save()

> save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True)

and saving image object

> image.image.save(image_name, ContentFile(response.read()), save=False)

Where is force_insert and force_update been used in this function?

Also i did not understand the parameter part in image.image.save() because image has field like title, url, description, image etc. What image_name is refering to? I think response.read() part is for image field.

Could anyone please make me clear?

**Here is the code**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             related_name='images_created')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                   db_index=True)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                        related_name='images_liked',
                                        blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def image_create(request):
    """
    View for creating an Image using the JavaScript Bookmarklet.
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # form is sent
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # form data is valid
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            new_item = form.save(commit=False)
            # assign current user to the item
            new_item.user = request.user
            new_item.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Image added successfully')
            # redirect to new created item detail view
            return redirect(new_item.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        # build form with data provided by the bookmarklet via GET
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.GET)

    return render(request, 'images/image/create.html', {'section': 'images',
                                                        'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class ImageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('title', 'url', 'description')
        widgets = {
            'url': forms.HiddenInput,
        }

    def clean_url(self):
        url = self.cleaned_data['url']
        valid_extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg']
        extension = url.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
        if extension not in valid_extensions:
            raise forms.ValidationError('The given URL does not match valid image extensions.')
        return url

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        image = super(ImageCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        image_url = self.cleaned_data['url']
        image_name = '{}.{}'.format(slugify(image.title),
                                    image_url.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower())

        # download image from the given URL
        response = request.urlopen(image_url)
        image.image.save(image_name,
                         ContentFile(response.read()),
                         save=False)
        print('image',image)

        if commit:
            image.save()
        return image
```

**Update**

To create an image i have to use this url localhost:8000/images/create/?title=title for image&url=http://www.demo.com/image/image.jpg

Comment: I think there are two different save methods here, one that saves a Form, the first in your example, and the second that saves an ImageField, the second one in your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
image = super(ImageCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
```

In this statement we are assigning super function to a variable image.

super method is called with ImageCreateForm. Then whatever is returned with super() method, we call the save() method of forms.ModelForm with commit=False.

Now if you look in your model Image you will find "image" attribute which is of of type models.ImageField

For the purpose of understanding, let me rename "image" attribute of model as "image_of_model"

The ImageField has a method save of the form

```
save(name,content, save)

image.image.save(image_name,
                     ContentFile(response.read()),
                     save=False)
```

As per my given terminology the above statement becomes.

```
image.image_of_model.save(image_name,
                     ContentFile(response.read()),
                     save=False)
```

I hope this sorts out your confusion.